# Log4j doesnt update logging information on the server

Tags: java, log4j

We have the below Log4j that doesn't update the app-info.log file on the server.
However we added the same property code in the lower environment which works fine.

```
log4j.appender.AppInfo=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender    
log4j.appender.AppInfo.MaxFileSize=1000KB`enter code here`  
log4j.appender.AppInfo.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.AppInfo.File=/opt/ibm/build/logs/IVRWS/app-info.log
log4j.appender.AppInfo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AppInfo.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.AppInfo.Threshold=INFO
```

The permissions looks good for the file.  The file has old logging information like 2014,2015 
Can someone please assist me with the issue

Comment: I assume the `enter code here` is accidentally added?

Comment: Is there any error published anywhere else? A `boot.log` or similar?